# .NET Resource ANSI encoding

Tags: .net, encoding, resources

I have a .NET resource which is ANSI ISO 8859-1 encoding. But when I access my reosource in code like `MyResource.Resource1` it is read in some default encoding (may be `Encoding.Default` or something else).

I don't see a way to specify resource encoding.

Comment: Since this is a (compiled-in) resource, why not convert it to the correct encoding before embedding it?

Comment: All .NET tools deal with Unicode strings only.  If you want to preserve a string encoding then you'll have to make sure that it is stored as a binary resource.  There is not enough detail in your question to help you find the best way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you are getting the resource.  If you are using the [`GetManifestResoruceStream` method on the `Assembly` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream.aspx) (if it is an embedded resource), then you are getting a `Stream`; the encoding is left to you to decide.

If you are using the [`ResourceManager` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager.aspx) then you should use the [`GetStream` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ew66s9z.aspx); this will give you a `Stream` which you can then apply the desired encoding to.

Answer (score 0):

If you deal with TextFile resource check your resource.resx file (open it as a simple text file)
it should have something like that:

```
<data name="fms_P001_v001" type="System.Resources.ResXFileRef, System.Windows.Forms">
<value>..\Resources\fms_P001_v001.xml;System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089;utf-8</value>
```

At the end of <value> tag will be encoding of text file here it is **utf-8** change it to what you need.